# Different json encoders for different "depths"

Tags: python, json

I would like to write a json encoder that knows when to expand an object, or leave it in an abbreviated form.

The object I have, has many properties, some of which are collections of other objects (which in turn have their own properties which may be collections, ad infinitum). The `json.dumps` method could return very large strings if it recursed through all objects.

Is it possible to set a "depth" so that any objects found after that depth are not expanded further?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the non-decoded portions?

Comment: I could just supply `repr(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should figure out whether you're really getting a hard disk savings here. Don't think about it in percent difference, but the dollar cost of diskspace for the people running your program.

Second, I figured out a hacky way of doing this:

Copy the folder /Lib/json/ into a folder outside of the python install. Name the folder something like, say, `jsondepth`

Go to encoder.py and make 3 changes (Line numbers are from Python 2.7):

Line 411, change

```
def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
    if isinstance(o, basestring):
        yield _encoder(o)
```

to

```
def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
    if(_current_indent_level > SKIP_INDENT_LEVEL):
        yield 'null'
        return
    if isinstance(o, basestring):
        yield _encoder(o)
```

Line 335, change

```
def _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level):
    if not dct:
        yield '{}'
```

to

```
def _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level):
    if(_current_indent_level > SKIP_INDENT_LEVEL):
        yield 'null'
        return
    if not dct:
        yield '{}'
```

Line 282, change

```
def _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level):
    if not lst:
        yield '[]'
```

to

```
def _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level):
    if(_current_indent_level > SKIP_INDENT_LEVEL):
        yield 'null'
        return
    if not lst:
        yield '[]'
```

Line 5, change

```
try:
    from _json import encode_basestring_ascii as c_encode_basestring_ascii
except ImportError:
    c_encode_basestring_ascii = None
try:
    from _json import make_encoder as c_make_encoder
except ImportError:
    c_make_encoder = None
```

to

```
c_encode_basestring_ascii = None
c_make_encoder = None
```

Somewhere at the top of the file, (say line 13)

```
SKIP_INDENT_LEVEL = 4 # or whatever recursion depth you want.
```

Note that indentation must be enabled, or this completely falls apart. Also note that I didn't test this. No warranty expressed or implied :)

Comment: That's pretty fearless, to just go hack up the JSON encoder.  But this solution hard-codes the maximum depth, which I don't like.  And I much prefer the code to be in the project, and not to have to hack a Python installation to run the code.

Comment: If you copy the code out, you don't need to modify the python installation. I assume that your concern is that other apps using the json package will not work.

Comment: No, actually, I wasn't concerned about other apps; I was concerned you would need to put the modified JSON encoder file in the /usr/lib subdirectory tree (or its equivalent on Windows).  But I was making a silly mistake.  Of course you can copy the JSON encoder file into the project directory; just because it came from the Python library directory doesn't mean you must leave it there.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest is just to make a copy of your dict, editing the copy as you like, and then use the JSON library to JSON-encode your copy.

Copying a dictionary and stopping at a given level is a pretty simple problem with a recursive function like this:

```
def is_dict(x):
    return hasattr(x, "has_key")

def dict_copy_n(d_to_copy, max_levels):
    assert max_levels >= 0
    d = {}
    for k, v in d_to_copy.items():
        if is_dict(v):
            if max_levels > 0:
                d[k] = dict_copy_n(v, max_levels - 1)
            else:
                # set key to None; or, delete the else: case to just ignore
                d[k] = None
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

The above code copies everything unchanged until `max_levels` counts down to 0, at which point any key whose value is a `dict` is simply set to `None` in the copy dict.  You can easily edit the above code to set the key to some other value, or simply to not copy that key.

So use the above function to make a partial copy of the original, and then JSON-encode the copy.